# EXC BAD ACCESS occurring when cocos2d calls ccTouchEnded in CCMenu

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

This only happens once in a while.  When I step from a breakpoint in the method called by the menu item when pressed I end up at the end of the method and when I step out I eventually get to ccTouchEnded and then the bad access occurs.  Nothing shows up in the debug output window but I get a green arrow pointing to the main method with the error message.

Any ideas why this might occur?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So in case anyone has the same problem, I figured out what was happening.  I had a CCMenu containing several children.  When a child was tapped I did what I wanted with it and then removed it from the CCMenu via removeChild:cleanup: in the method I passed as the selector for the CCMenuItem.  The problem was that Cocos2d deactivates the CCMenuItem while the selector method is executed and then reactivates it when the method is finished.  So in the method I was basically destroying the CCMenuItem by removing it from the CCMenu and then at the end of the method Cocos2d tried to reactivate it but it was no longer in memory.

I don't see much of a way around this, so maybe it is not possible to remove a CCMenuItem from a CCMenu in its selector method.

The way I worked around it was to simply call setVisible:NO and setIsEnabled:NO on the menuitem.  However, I can imagine cases in which this would not be the best way to do it.  Maybe in these cases you could mess with the z position or something to get the menuitem out of the way.

Anyway, I hope this helps someone else, I know I've been stuck on this a while. :)

Comment: ah ha ! mystery explained, thanks Mason. I ended up nuking the menu and recreating it when needing 'badly' to remove a menu item altogether.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution, in my humble opinion, is to unwind the scene destruction call from the stack. Using something like NSTimer+BlockKit makes it really clean. Here's an excerpt from my code:

```
- (void)menuAction
{
    // we use a timer here to delay the execution of the action because it
    // destroys the current scene and we're mid a call on CCMenu's ccTouchEnded
    // that isn't expecting a scene tear down
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165822/exc-bad-access-occurring-when-cocos2d-calls-cctouchended-in-ccmenu
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0 block:^(NSTimer* timer)
    {
       [[CCDirector sharedDirector] popSceneWithTransition:
         [CCTransitionSlideInL class] duration:kTransDur];
    }
    repeats:NO];
}
```